# Cleaning the message of a custom exception

Tags: exception, grails

In my grails app I have a custom `InvalidTokenException` as follows:

```
class InvalidTokenException extends Exception{  

  public InvalidTokenException() {}

  public InvalidTokenException(String message)
  {
    super(message);
  }  
}
```

which I am throwing in my service as follows:

```
throw new InvalidTokenException("Invalid token : '${word}'")
```

which I am catching in my controller and rendering to the client as follows:

```
catch(e)
    {
        //send the exception to the client for rendering an error message.
        render(status: 400, text: e)
        return false //stops further execution
    }
```

Though I want to be strip back the message that it only contains the text "Invalid token : word" rather than "Exception uk.co.litecollab.exceptions.InvalidTokenException Invalid token : word"

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `render(status: 400, text: e.message)` since you're currently taking advantage of the auto-conversion of `e` to a String, which calls the `toString()` method. Calling `getMessage()` directly makes more sense in general and does what you need here.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.  Should have caught this myself, its been a long weekend..